# Unable to use variable as command argument inside for loop

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to execute a command inside a for loop. The command expects a parameter which i'm trying to pass through a variable

I tried different approaches (with brackets, without brackets, quoutes, no quotes, ect) and I've been searching bash documentation, with no success (I'm not an expert on bash anyway).

```
JQ="jq --raw-output --exit-status"

service_array="$(aws ecs list-services --cluster "mycluster" | JQ ".serviceArns")"

for service in $(echo "${service_array}" |  JQ '.[]'); do
  echo "Updating service: " ${service} # Works
  aws ecs update-service --cluster "mycluster" --service ${service} --force-new-deployment # Doesn't work
done
```

Expected result is to execute the command, actual result is that only the echo command seems to work.

The service_array is correctly populated, and the command works fine when I execute it outside the for loop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You define `JQ` as a variable, but use `JQ` instead of its expansion `$JQ`. So unless you have a function `JQ` or an executable `JQ` in your path, this certainly doesn't work (and doesn't qualify as a mwe).

Comment: JQ works fine. Did you see the first line of the snippet?

Comment: Yes I did. But did you understand my comment?

Comment: No, it doesn't work! how could it? unless you have an executable `JQ` in your path or a function `JQ`. Can you please add the line `type -a JQ` to your script and run it?

Comment: Updated providing an example that you could execute (if you have jq available) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459493/10994698

Comment: As said, it doesn't work, for the reason I mentioned. `:)`. Can you please add the line `type -a JQ` to your script and run it? (and see what `JQ` really is).

Comment: I appreciate your attention, running it directly with jq instead of JQ has the same behaviour (jq is a json parser by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Without more info I can only assume that `service` contains white space or other special characters and so needs to be quoted:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster "mycluster" --service "${service}" --force-new-deployment # Doesn't work
```

Note: you should probably add similar quoting to the `echo` command too, although it is less important there, since `echo` does not care if arguments get broken up or expanded into multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried "${service}", "$service", $service and ${service}: all work fine outside the loop but inside the loop none of them work...

Comment: OK - well stick with the quotes anyway. It looks like the problem identified by @gniourf-gniourf in the comments above may be what you need to address.